# Xamarin.iOS UITabBarItem very low resolution

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get started with Xamarin for iOS and have already run into a problem where my custom UITabBarItems are much lower resolution than the default UITabBarSystemItems.

Here's some code where I make 2 UITabBarItems, one with a custom icon and one with a system icon.

```
        UIImage image = new UIImage("Images/wheel_icon.png");
        result.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem("Spin", image, 1);

        result.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem(UITabBarSystemItem.More, 2);
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvIJj.png)

As you can see the Spin icon is much lower resolution than the More icon. I have tried many different resolutions, but anything larger than 30x30 goes outside the boundaries of the TabBar. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It may be your resource's problem. Try larger resolutions, and make sure add suffix to your image name(i.e. imagename@2x.png, imagename@3x.png).

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at those two documents:

- [Image Size and Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/)
- [Custom Icons > Custom Icon Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

Then check if you're supporting devices with "normal resolution", for a minimum version of iOS 11 for example that's not the case anymore, as all supported devices have a retina display and therefore require @2x or @3x (iPhone 6|7|8 Plus).

That being said, you then load the icon from your bundle simply without giving a concrete extension: `UIImage image = new UIImage("wheel_icon");`

That enables iOS to chose the right version (@2x or @3x).

As you can see, it's not related to Xamarin, but iOS .-).